# Find the Mode of a List

Tags: python-3.x

```
L = [98,75,92,87,89,90,92,87]

def mode(L):

    shows = []
    modeList = []

    L.sort()

    length = len(L)

    for num in L:
        count = L.count(num)
        shows.append(count)

    print 'List = ', L

    maxI = shows.index(max(shows))

    for i in shows:
        if i == maxI:
            if modeList == []:
                mode = L[i]
                modeList.append(mode)
                print 'Mode = ', mode
            elif mode not in modeList:
                mode = L[i]
                modeList.append(mode)
                print 'Mode = ', mode
            return mode


mode(L)
```

I can't seem to iterate through my list properly...
I can successfully get the first Mode to return >>>(Mode = 87) using the 2nd for-loop however, I can't get it to search the rest of the list so that it will also return >>>(Mode = 92)

I've deleted my attempts at Mode = 92, can you help fill in the blanks?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you asking the same question [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364464/python-3-find-the-mode-of-a-list)?

Answer (score 0):

the same idea with `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

L = [98,75,92,87,89,90,92,87]

def mode(L):
    # count the occurring frequencies
    count = Counter(L)

    # find the max
    mx = max(count.values())

    # collect the frequencies that occur the most
    modes = [f for f, m in count.items() if  m == mx]

    return modes

print(mode(L))
# [87, 92]
```

Answer (score -2):

Good job on the code. I rewrote it a little. See below code:

```
L = [98,75,92,87,89,90,92,87]

def mode(L):

    # Create a frequency table
    freq = {}
    for num in L:
        if not num in freq:
            freq[num] = 1
        else:
            freq[num] += 1

    # Gets maximal occurence
    maxoccurence = 0
    for f in freq:
        maxoccurence = max(maxoccurence, freq[f])

    # Put all the numbers with the occurence in  a list
    modes = []
    for f in freq:
        if freq[f] == maxoccurence:
            modes += [f]

    # Returns the list
    return modes

print(mode(L))
```